# A verification of Pigeon hole Principle

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering that the generalization of Pigeon hole Principle states that :

> If $kn+1$ pigeons are distributed in $n$ holes, then some  hole has atleast $k+1$ pigeons.

This is quite obvious intuitively however, if we consider that amongst let's say $nk$ pigeons of $nk+1$ of them are considered and  those $nk$ pigeons are first distributed in $n $ holes. So, if some holes has $k$ pigeons and some of them has less than $k$ pigeons ...Then is this situation possible as then we can keep the $1$ remaining pigeon in the hole containing less than $k$ pigeons and then all the $n$ holes has less than k+1 pigeons ...then it doesn't verify the Pigeon hole principle stated above...where is the problem occurring?

Comment: [1] Typo, should be : "...then some hole has atleast $k+1$ pigeons" not $n+1$ pigeons.  This is assuming that you are distributing $(nk+1)$ pigeons among $n$ pigeonholes.  [2] Assume that you have $n$ pigeonholes, none of which has more than $k$ pigeons.  Then, the maximum number of pigeons being stored is $k \times n$ pigeons, among the $n$ pigeonholes.  Therefore, if you then go to add the $[nK + 1]$-th pigeon, among the $n$ pigeonholes, at least one of the pigeonholes must contain more than $k$ pigeons.

Comment: @user2661923 yeah, thanks for pointing out the typo... however the thing which u prove as $[2]$ only refers to a particular case or the "maximum case" when we consider that each hole has k pigeons.....

Comment: The "maximum case" is all that needs to be considered.  Ask yourself, if you have $[(nk) + 1]$ pigeons to be distributed into $n$ pigeonholes, is there any way that none of the $n$ pigeonholes has more than $k$ pigeons.  If you experiment with various small values for $n$ and $k$, you should be able to convince yourself that the answer, for general values of $n$ and $k$ is **NO**.

Comment: @user2661923 yes ur right ....but also I got a proof ...if lets say some of those holes has  $ k$ pigeons and some of them have less than $k$ pigeons together making up for nk pigeons in total in those n holes. Now lets say $x$of them has k pigeons and y of the holes has less than k pigeons i.e $a$ (say) such that $ a<k $ Now, the maximum value of $a$ is $k-1$ so, if we have the equation $xk+ya=nk$ and $n-x=y$ then $ya=(n-x)k$ which implies $ya= ka$ so, $a=k$ , but this is a contraction as $a<k$ ...so this case  is not possible....

Comment: If none of the $n$ holes have more than $k$ pigeons, and some of the pigeonholes have less than $k$ pigeons, then it is **impossible** that as many as $(n \times k)$ pigeons are being stored.  I repeat:  **experiment with small numbers and your intuition will be stretched**.

Answer (score 2):

### Move the pigeons around

Here's one way to put $kn$ pigeons into $n$ holes: put $k$ pigeons into each hole so that each hole has the same number.

Now if you want to put the pigeons into the holes in a different way, you can just move these pigeons around.  But if you move any pigeons around, notice that some of the holes will have more than $k$ pigeons and some of the holes will have less than $k$ pigeons. ***The only way one of the holes can have *less* than $k$ pigeons in it is if another hole has more than $k$ pigeons in it.***

So: when you put $nk$ pigeons into $n$ holes, either

1. Some of the holes have more than $k$ pigeons and some have less than $k$ pigeons. Then the generalized pigeonhole principle is already established in this case.
2. All of the holes have exactly the same number of pigeons, $k$. Adding one more pigeon to any hole will establish the generalized pigeonhole principle in this case.

---

### Or notice that there aren't enough pigeons

First you put $kn$ pigeons into $n$ holes, then you'll decide what to do with the last pigeon.

If any of the holes has more than $k$ pigeons in it already, you're done—you've proved the generalized pigeonhole principle for this case.

Otherwise, all of the holes have $k$ pigeons or fewer. But remember we said the total number of pigeons must be $kn$.  Note that in order to add up to the correct total, every hole must have exactly $k$ pigeons in it. It's impossible for any hole to have less than $k$ pigeons in it in this case.

Why? If even one hole has $k-1$ pigeons in it and the other holes all have $k$ pigeons, then the total number of pigeons is $kn-1$—too small. We're missing some pigeons.

So when you say:

> if some holes has $k$ pigeons and some of them has less than $k$ pigeons

This is where the mistake is— you imagine that you can have less than $k$ pigeons in a hole when this is impossible. If you put $nk$ pigeons into $n$ holes, and no hole has *more* than $k$ pigeons, then no hole has *less* than $k$ pigeons, either.

Comment: but also I got a proof ...if lets say some of those holes has  $ k$ pigeons and some of them have less than $k$ pigeons together making up for nk pigeons in total in those n holes. Now lets say $x$of them has k pigeons and y of the holes has less than k pigeons i.e $a$ (say) such that $ a<k $ Now, the maximum value of $a$ is $k-1$ so, if we have the equation $xk+ya=nk$ and $n-x=y$ then $ya=(n-x)k$ which implies $ya= ka$ so, $a=k$ , but this is a contraction as $a<k$ ...so this case  is not possible to have some boxes more than $k$ pigeons and some having less than $k$ pigeons....

Comment: I think this is a valid proof ..isnt it?

Comment: @Franklin Yes, you've proved that if you put $nk$ pigeons into $n$ holes and every hole has $k$ or $k-1$ pigeons, then all of the holes must have $k$ pigeons.

Comment: @user326210...Yeah, that was the point ...thank you so much!

Comment: @Franklin Yeah! It helped me to experiment with a specific example, e.g. when $n=3$ and $k=4$, you can try different ways to put 12+1 pigeons into 3 holes.

Comment: ur proof method by the arrangement 1 is great! But I just went on a bit rigorous way by contradiction to prove the case impossible( as mentioned by me on the 1st comment) ....but thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If for $i=1,\ldots,n$ there are $p_i$ pigeons in hole $i$ and if we assume that $p_i\le k$, then the total number $p$ of pigeons is
$$ p=p_1+p_2+\cdots +p_n\le k+k+\cdots +k=nk.$$
Hence,

> If all $p_i$ are $\le k$, then $p\le nk$.

which is equivalent to

> If not $p\le nk$, then not all $p_i$ are $\le k$.

or,

> If $p>nk$, then there is some $i$ with $p_i>k$.